# RecyclerView and saving+retrieving temporary states per adapter item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

If a`ViewHolder's` `itemView`has`setActivated(.)`called, that information is carried on after the view is recycled (i.e. the next will also be activated if the previous was).

Where would be a good place to save and store this information per item in the adapter rather than per itemView in the recycler; make items in the adapter a separate holder with an item and a boolean and then save it in`onViewRecycled(.)`as well as conditionally call`setActivated(.)`again in`onBind(.)`?

Or are there better approaches altogether? (I was thinking`ListView`might be more intuitively, but unless`RecyclerView`is strongly discouraged for this typ of task, I'd prefer to use it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up creating a small local and private class that holds the status as well as the object. For now the status only includes a boolean `isSelected`, but I suppose it could be expanded and turned into a full fledged class in its own, when needed.